# Para que servem tipos aninhados?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem

Eu sei que o C# suporta tipos aninhados, ou seja, é possível eu declarar uma classe dentro de outra. Por exemplo:

```
public class A
{
    // Propriedades e métodos da classe A

    public class B
    {
         // Propriedades e métodos da classe B
    }
}
```

Só nunca entendi para que serve isso. Para que essa construção pode ser usada e quais os benefícios?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O mais comum é para usar o tipo interno como privado e assim ele funciona como um tipo auxiliar que só pode ser acessado internamente. É uma forma de composição com um tipo que só diz respeito ao tipo em questão. Ou seja, se o tipo interno não será usado em outro lugar não tem porque expô-lo para outras partes do código.

Você pode assim esconder um detalhe de implementação deixando mais organizado a parte que é o detalhe. Na maioria dos casos é uma questão de organização.

Um detalhe importante é que o tipo interno pode acessar membros do tipo externo, mesmo os privados, sem problemas se for necessário. Tudo que foi criado em um escopo mais externo continua no mesmo escopo. O aninamento funciona de forma idêntica ao encontrado em algoritmos de métodos.

Não saberia citar um exemplo onde seria apropriado criar um tipo aninhado que seja público.

Pesquisando achei alguns exemplos interessantes no SO, especialmente na [resposta do Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1084255/221800) onde ele mostra uma forma onde você pode criar sua própria hierarquia mas impedir que outros o façam:

```
public abstract class BankAccount {
    private BankAccount() {} // prevent third-party subclassing.
    private sealed class SavingsAccount : BankAccount { ... }
    private sealed class ChequingAccount : BankAccount { ... }
    public static BankAccount MakeSavingAccount() { ... }
    public static BankAccount MakeChequingAccount() { ... }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/NestedType.cs).

Note que ele usa `private` e não deixa o *default*. Em C# classes, por *default* são `internal`, ou seja são visíveis por todo *assembly*. Seria quase a mesma coisa que deixar `public`, afinal você está criando uma classe dentro de outra mas ela seria acessível fora dela, então não teria muita vantagem.

Comment: Não sei como é com C#, mas se me lembro bem em Java havia uma outra utilidade para tipos aninhados, mesmo públicos - garantir uma relação de composição entre o tipo "de fora" e o "de dentro". Pois se para construir uma instância do interno você precisa sempre de uma referência pro externo (ex.: `a = new A(); b = a.new B()`) garante-se que a composição exista e o `A` nunca seja nulo (embora o *namespace* de `B` fique poluído com os membros internos de `A`...). Não sei se isso faz sentido em C# - ou mesmo se é uma boa ideia em Java - mas fica aí o exemplo.

Answer (score 11):

Basicamente, limitação de escopo, mas farei uma pequena mudança para que a utilidade seja melhor entendida:

```
public class A
{
    // Propriedades e métodos da classe A

    class B
    {
         // Propriedades e métodos da classe B
    }
}
```

Repare que retirei o `public` de `B`. Isto porque o aninhamento de classes só é verdadeiramente útil quando `B` for protegido dentro da declaração de `A`.

E por que isso?

Porque pode ser que sua aplicação faça uso da classe apenas internamente. Um ótimo exemplo seria usando o padrão de design `Factory` juntamente com herança e classes imutáveis. Vamos usar um exemplo concreto:

```
public abstract class ContaBancaria
{
    private ContaBancaria() { }
    private sealed class ContaPoupanca : ContaBancaria { ... }
    private sealed class ContaCorrente : ContaBancaria { ... }
    public static ContaBancaria CriarContaCorrente() { ... }
    public static ContaBancaria CriarContaPoupanca() { ... }
}
```

Neste caso, garanto que o que vai ser devolvido será ou uma `ContaCorrente` ou uma `ContaPoupanca`, sendo as duas derivadas de `ContaBancaria`, sem poder estendê-las (o que poderia ser um problema de segurança) e sem a capacidade de explorar construtores, caso essa classe faça parte de uma API, por exemplo.