# Colocar o construtor da classe como 'private'?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Ao colocar um construtor de uma classe no C# como `private`, obtenho o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber qual a explicação técnica para o motivo deste erro e se há algum caso de uso   de construtor (ou um dos construtores) de uma classe como `private`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Temos várias boas respostas aqui mas já que eu resmunguei de alguma coisa em cada uma delas, acho que é justo eu expor a minha própria.

Como já dito, o motivo do erro é que você está tentando utilizar um membro da classe (o construtor) que não está acessível fora dela devido ao fato de ser privado.

E sim, existem casos de uso ou utilidade em se declarar um construtor como privado:

> Declare um construtor privado quando desejar que este construtor esteja acessível apenas à própria classe e às suas classes aninhadas.

Algumas vezes apenas a própria classe conhece suas restrições para ser instanciada, então é nessas horas que você declara o construtor como *private*. Estas restrições podem ser:

- A classe quer restringir apenas uma única instância sua ao longo de todo o ciclo de vida do aplicativo (*design pattern singleton*).
- A classe quer controlar suas instâncias - por exemplo fazendo um pool de instâncias de si mesma, então ela própria cria suas instâncias (*design pattern factory*) e decide quando entregar uma nova instância ou quando entregar uma instância já existente.
- A classe exige que consumidores externos passem certos parâmetros ao construtor mas quer poder criar instâncias dela mesma sem passar nenhum parâmetro ou passando parâmetros que não interessam publicamente. Neste caso ela teria construtores parametrizados públicos e um construtor privado não parametrizado ou que aceite parâmetros específicos que só precisam ser conhecidos internamente.

Estes são os usos que me ocorrem no momento mas pode haver mais.

Além de *public* e *private*, um construtor também pode ser **protected**, que faz com que ele possa ser usado exclusivamente pelo constutor de classes filhas, e **internal**, que o torna acessível apenas para classes do mesmo *assembly*.

**Internal** é útil por exemplo para utilizar o *design pattern factory* ou pool de instâncias fazendo com que outra classe do mesmo contexto é que seja responsável por estas restrições em vez de colocar todo este conhecimento dentro da própria classe cuja instanciação se quer controlar.

Quanto a criar um construtor privado para classes estáticas, não é muito útil pois neste caso basta declarar a própria classe como estática (*static class*).

Answer (score 15):

Um construtor privado é útil nos casos onde você quer impedir que a classe seja instanciada ou quer permitir que ela seja instanciada apenas dentro dela própria. Isto é útil para classes estáticas ou para implementar os padrões de projeto [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) e [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Um exemplo pode ser encontrado [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51616/101). Outros exemplo obviamente estão nas outras respostas aqui.

Singleton ([retirado da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton#Em_C.23)):

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var singleton = MyClass.Instance;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
   private static MyClass instance;
   private MyClass() {}
   public static MyClass Instance {
      get {
         if (instance == null) instance = new MyClass();
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/1Lge8B). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IEfqlO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Singleton.cs).

Comment: Só não é útil para classes estáticas declaradas como tal pois uma classe declarada como estática não pode ser instanciada e sequer pode ter construtores, mesmo que privados.

Comment: @Caffé sim, claro.

Comment: @Caffé Todas as classes possuem construtor, os construtores de classes estáticas são mais restritivos, mas existem. Leia minha resposta para ver um exemplo.

Comment: @Malkaviano Pois é, até já usei este tipo de construtor. Mas não tem nada a ver com declarar um construtor como privado a fim de torná-lo inacessível - um construtor estático sequer aceita modificadores de acesso.

Answer (score 9):

A explicação técnica é simples: o construtor não pode ser acessado de fora da classe. Por isso o erro.

Construtores privados são importantes quando você quiser forçar parâmetros para os construtores expostos (públicos). Por exemplo, construtores sem parâmetros poderiam ser declarados como privados para que seu uso seja evitado. Há uma ressalva aqui: o construtor sem parâmetros precisa fazer alguma coisa, senão sua declaração não faz sentido.

Por exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasse 
{
    protected int MeuInteiroQuePrecisaSerPreenchido { get; set; }
    protected int OutraProperty { get; set; }

    // inacessível, portanto não pode ser usado fora da classe.
    private MinhaClasse() 
    { 
        OutraProperty = 5;
    } 

    // Aqui eu chamo o construtor sem parâmetros. 
    public MinhaClasse(int _meuInteiro) : this()
    {
        MeuInteiroQuePrecisaSerPreenchido = _meuInteiro;
    }
}
```

[Por padrão, o construtor sem parâmetros de uma classe é público](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Ainda, suponha que você queira definir construtores diversos (para verificação de dados dos argumentos, por exemplo). Você pode fazer construtores com níveis variados de proteção:

```
public class MinhaClasse2
{
    protected int MeuInteiro { get; set; }
    protected int OutraProperty { get; set; }
    protected String MinhaStringComValidacao { get; set; }

    // inacessível, portanto não pode ser usado fora da classe.
    private MinhaClasse() 
    { 
        OutraProperty = 5;
    } 

    private MinhaClasse(String _minhaString) : this()
    {
        if (_minhaString != "Valor que não pode") 
        {
            MinhaStringComValidacao = _minhaString;
        }
    }

    public MinhaClasse(int _meuInteiro, String _minhaString) : this(_minhaString)
    {
        MeuInteiro = _meuInteiro;
    }
}
```

Exemplo bobo, mas apenas para demonstrar como pode ser feito.

Comment: Se o construtor não pode ser utilizado, qual a real utilidade de até mesmo declarar ele?

Comment: @LuisHenrique Forçar o programador a utilizar um construtor com parâmetros, ou como na resposta do André Ribeiro, evitar que classes estáticas possam ser instanciadas.

Comment: O primeiro motivo apresentado é inválido. Uma classe que só tenha construtores parametrizados não pode ser instanciada utilizando um construtor não parametrizado - o compilador não permite; não é necessário declarar explicitamente um construtor não parametrizado como private.

Comment: O @Caffé está certo

Comment: Não está. Posso perfeitamente implementar uma classe genérica com a declaração `where T: class, new()`. Numa classe sem a declaração `private`, o código passa e o objeto é instanciado sem problemas. O primeiro argumento evita que isso possa ser usado.

Comment: O @Caffé esta' correcto, sim. Observa: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YyElx9.

Comment: O 2o motivo tambem e' invalido. Classes estaticas (declaradas como `static class SomeClass{}`), por definicao, nao podem ser instanciadas. Entao, dizer que constructores privados servem para "evitar que classes estáticas possam ser instanciadas" nem faz sentido. Talvez faca sentido em java, onde classes nao podem ser declaradas como estaticas, mas nao em c#.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, uma classe que tenha apenas construtores parametrizados não pode ser passada para um generic que exija um construtor não parametrizado - isso já é impedido pelo compilador sem necessidade de declarar um construtor privado. Veja: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5xTFHJ

Comment: @Caffé, eu concordo com o Cigano, eu posso ter um classe com contrutor private e propriedades staticas do mesmo tipo da classe a qual pertencem, desta forma apenas os objetos iniciados atraves das propriedades estaticas podem ser acessados.

Comment: @TobyMosque Entendo que este seja um bom motivo para se ter construtores privados. Mas ninguém está questionando sua utilidade, estamos questionando a utilidade conforme proposta por Cigano, que não tem nada a ver com isso.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Apos a edicao: o primeiro exemplo nao faz sentido, o constructor nunca sera chamado - nao ha necessidade de ser declarado. O 2o exemplo tambem nao tem utilidade, nao ha razao para o "null check" nao ser feito dentro do constructor publico.

Comment: Não tô discutindo o mérito da utilidade. Só estou apontando o que pode ser feito.

Comment: Mas a questao e' precisamente sobre a utilidade desta feature, nao sobre como usa-la: "se há algum caso de uso/utilidade em usar um construtor(ou um dos construtores) de uma classe como private"

Comment: Então por favor leia minha edição e não se reduza a críticas. Apenas criticar em nada agrega a este site ou à dúvida feita.

Comment: Eu li a edicao, e fiz uma critica constructiva porque nao considero a resposta util, e nao esclarece a duvida colocada. Discordo dessa ultima frase: criticar ajuda imenso. De qualquer modo, tambem ja escrevi a minha propria resposta - aceito criticas.

Answer (score 6):

[Segundo a documentação na MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/kcfb85a6.aspx)

> Um construtor privado é um construtor de instância especial. Ele é
>   geralmente usado em classes que contêm apenas membros estáticos. Se
>   uma classe tem um ou mais construtores privados e nenhum
>   construtor público, outras classes (exceto classes aninhadas) não podem
>   criar instâncias dessa classe.
>
> Por exemplo:

```
class NLog
{
    // Construtor privado:
    private NLog() { }

    public static double e = Math.E;  //2.71828...
}
```

> A declaração do construtor vazio impede que a geração automática de um
>   construtor padrão. Observe que se você não especificar um modificador de
>   acesso o construtor ainda será privado por padrão. No entanto, o
>   modificador `private` geralmente é usado explicitamente para deixar claro
>   que a classe não pode ser instanciada.
>
> Construtores
>   privados são usadas para evitar a criação de instâncias de uma
>   classe quando não existem campos de instância ou métodos, como na classe Math,
>   ou quando um método é chamado para obter uma instância de uma
>   classe. *Caso todos os métodos da classe sejam estáticos, considere tornar a classe inteira estática.*

**Exemplo:**

```
public class Counter
{
    private Counter() { }
    public static int currentCount;
    public static int IncrementCount()
    {
        return ++currentCount;
    }
}

class TestCounter
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // A instrução abaixo irá gerar um erro porque o construtor é inacessível
        // Counter aCounter = new Counter();   // Erro

        Counter.currentCount = 100;
        Counter.IncrementCount();
        Console.WriteLine("New count: {0}", Counter.currentCount);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
// Output: New count: 101
```

Comment: Uma classe que só tenha membros estáticos pode ser declarada como estática ela mesma, de modo a dispensar a declaração do construtor privado pois uma classe estática não pode ser instanciada. Nonsense esta sentença desta documentação da Microsoft.

Comment: @Caffé Melhorei a tradução do último paragrafo que não estava boa. Dê uma olhada na última frase.

Answer (score 4):

Eis um caso concreto, implementado pela propria equipa do ASP.NET Web Api no GitHub: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Results/OkResult.cs

Eu proprio ja' apliquei o mesmo padrao [aqui](https://github.com/dcastro/JSendWebApi/blob/master/src/JSendWebApi/Results/JSendResult.cs).

Resumidamente, os dois links acima mostram uma variacao do padrao ["Parameter Object"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject).
Os constructores publicos da classe recebem ou as suas dependencias directamente, ou outro objecto que contem as suas dependencias.

Ambos os constructores publicos envolvem os argumentos numa instancia de `IDependencyProvider`, que e' passada para um constructor privado que extrai as dependencias e trata-as uniformemente. Este constructor e' considerado um detalhe de implementacao, os clientes nao precisam de saber dele, e portanto e' privado.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly string _dependency1;
    private readonly string _dependency2;

    public MyClass(string dependency1, int dependency2)
        : this(new DirectDependencyProvider(dependency1, dependency2))
    {
    }

    public MyClass(Container container)
        : this(new ContainerDependencyProvider(container))
    {
    }

    //constructor privado
    private MyClass(IDependencyProvider provider)
    {
        _dependency1 = provider.Dependency1;
        _dependency2 = provider.Dependency2;

        //etc, fazer alguma coisa com as duas dependencias
    }

    private interface IDependencyProvider
    {
        string Dependency1 { get; }
        int Dependency2 { get; }
    }

    private class DirectDependencyProvider : IDependencyProvider
    {
        private readonly string _dependency1;
        private readonly int _dependency2;

        public DirectDependencyProvider(string dependency1, int dependency2)
        {
            _dependency1 = dependency1;
            _dependency2 = dependency2;
        }

        public string Dependency1
        {
            get { return _dependency1; }
        }

        public int Dependency2
        {
            get { return _dependency2; }
        }
    }

    private class ContainerDependencyProvider : IDependencyProvider
    {
        private readonly Container _container;

        public ContainerDependencyProvider(Container container)
        {
            if(container == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            _container = container;
        }

        public string Dependency1
        {
            get { return _container.StringStuff; }
        }

        public int Dependency2
        {
            get { return _container.IntStuff; }
        }
    }
}
```

Nota que a interface `IDependencyProvider` e as suas implementacoes sao tipos privados.

A alternativa seria usar um metodo privado de inicializacao, mas teriamos de sacrificar os fields `readonly` e a garantia da sua imutabilidade. Esse e' um sacrificio que pode e **deve** ser evitado.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _dependency1;
    private string _dependency2;

    public MyClass(string dependency1, int dependency2)
    {
        Initialize(dependency1, dependency2);
    }

    public MyClass(Container container)
    {
        if(container == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

        Initialize(container.StringStuff, container.IntStuff);
    }

    private void Initialize(string dependency1, int dependency2)
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
        _dependency2 = dependency2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal trazer um exemplo prático. Eu até aprimorei o terceiro caso de uso da minha resposta, inspirado por esta aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Um outro caso de uso para um construtor privado seria para implementar o design pattern Singleton. Segundo esse padrão, uma classe deve ter somente uma instância. Para garantir isso, o construtor de um Singleton é privado. Mais informações: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton. Só lembrando que o Singleton é útil em apenas algumas situações. Ele tem uma série de desvantagens( por exemplo, ele dificulta os testes ), então deve ser usado com cuidado.

Comment: Singleton só dificulta os testes se as depências que se tem dele não forem explícitas. Se eu desejo ter apenas uma instância de uma classe durante todo o ciclo de vida do aplicativo, é natural eu usar um Singleton. Se eu desejo ter um bom design, eu vou passar este singleton por parâmetro para quem precisar dele, de modo que o singleton em si não causa nenhum problema. Objetos mutáveis globais e dependências ocultas é que causam problema.

Comment: Concordo com o ponto das dependências ocultas. Dependências ocultas são péssimas, especialmente porque elas acabam com a flexibilidade do código, dificultam testes e tornam o código que usa essas dependências extremamente propenso a violar o princípio Open-Closed. Mas ainda acho que singletons são difíceis de se testar. Você citou o lado de usar um singleton como dependência, mas e o teste do Singleton em si? Como "mockar" um singleton?

Comment: Você mocka a dependência (cria um mock da dependência) para testar o código dependente, não faz sentido mockar aquilo que se vai testar. Se você vai testar o próprio singleton, você não vai mockar ele; e se vai testar algo que dependa do singleton, desde que a dependência que se tem dele esteja explícita você pode mocka-lo normalmente usado polimorfismo (por herança ou por implementação de interface).

Comment: E se o Singleton fizer uma requisição HTTP qualquer? Nesse caso, não faria sentido mockar a classe? Testes unitários não devem depender de rede...

Comment: Então você quer ter uma única instância (singleton) de uma classe que dependa de comunicação HTTP, e você quer poder testar unitariamente esta classe mockando esta dependência? Faça assim: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pg8qb5

Comment: E se a classe ComunicacaoHttp fosse um Singleton e você quisesse testá-la? O que estou falando é de um Singleton que faça ele mesmo uma requisição HTTP e não de um Singleton que use uma dependência para isso...

Comment: Você pode desenhar sua solução do jeito que quiser. Eu prefiro desenhar de um jeito onde tudo seja testável e eu ainda possa usar uma única instância de uma classe durante todo o ciclo de vida do aplicativo se eu precisar.

Comment: O que você postou é diferente do problema que eu apontei. Você testou um singleton que depende de uma classe que faz uma requisição HTTP e não um singleton que faz a comunicação HTTP ele mesmo. Ou seja, estamos falando de situações diferentes. O que eu queria salientar é que, se você não pode mockar um Singleton, então isso é uma das desvantagens dele, é o que faz ele dificultar os testes...

Comment: Não, classes das quais você deseja apenas uma instância não são difíceis de testar - as minhas, embora poucas, eu testo bem facinho. Designs ruins de maneira geral é que são difíceis de testar. Você está criando uma restrição desnecessária no seu singleton para daí dizer que singletons são difíceis de testar - é claro que é mais fácil fazer um design ruim que um design bom, mas se você conseguir fazer um design bom, sem restrições desnecessárias, você pode ter instâncias únicas de classes com dependências e ainda assim testáveis, como no meu exemplo.

Comment: Sim...singletons são difíceis de testar. Você fugiu da situação que eu propus. O que eu quis mostrar é que Singletons não podem ser mockados, e isso dificulta os testes. E isso é uma limitação, tanto é que você está fugindo da situação que eu propus...como desculpa, parece que você quer dar a entender que o meu design é ruim sem ver sequer uma linha de código que eu escrevi.

Comment: Um design que não se pode testar em uma linguagem tão moderna, é um design ruim. Se você tem instâncias únicas de classes com dependências (uma necessidade natural) que você não pode testar, teu design é ruim. Eu não fugi de nada, apenas te dei opções de fazer o que você propôs como desafio (testar classes com dependências das quais você necessita uma única instância). Se você prefere uma solução não testável, go for it.

Comment: Acho que você não está entendendo. Parece que você está achando que eu tenho um singleton que faz uma requisição HTTP no meu projeto. Não está claro que o que falei foi apenas para mostrar o problema dos singletons? Quando eu falei que eu tenho um singleton que faz uma requisição HTTP em algum projeto? Foi apenas um exemplo exatamente para mostrar uma deficiência dos singletons. Você não pode mockar singletons, e isso é um problema. Como algo que não se pode mockar não dificulta os testes? Os singletons colocam uma barreira nos testes.

Comment: Existem mil maneiras de mockar um singleton. Eu te dei uma boa opção de como mockar objetos dos quais você deseja uma única instância, e este artigo do Uncle Bob publicado ontem oferece mais algumas boas opções e boas idéias que podem te ajudar a superar este mito de que "singleton é intestável e é do mal": http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/07/01/TheLittleSingleton.html. Boa leitura!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a maioria dos usos é quando queremos manter um DDD e o framework nos obriga a ter construtor padrão, exemplo é o Entity Framework que obriga todas as entidades persistidas a terem construtores sem parâmetro, mas não se importa com a visibilidade. Como você que segue o DDD e não quer modelos "anêmicos" não deseja que os usuários da classe consigam usar esses construtores e usa desse recurso para escondê-los.

Eu concordo que eles também servem para proteger classes com métodos puramente estáticos, mas aí tem o recurso de declarar a classe estática, questão de design.

@Caffé: Todas as classes possuem construtores, inclusive as estáticas. Claro que esses construtores possuem maiores restrições.

Perceba (linqpad):

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Xpto.msg);
}

static class Xpto
{
    public static string msg;

    static Xpto()
    {
        msg = "Blau";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, e isto é bastante útil por exemplo para definir a ordem de inicialização de fields da classe. Mas não tem tem nenhuma relação com declaração de construtores privados.