# Classes estáticas e classes com métodos estáticos

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Quando eu declaro uma classe `static`, sou obrigado a escrever meus métodos estáticos e essa classe jamais poderá ser instanciadas. Agora, eu tenho uma classe comum e crio meus métodos dentro dela todos estáticos. Bem, eu até considero essa classe estática, por consideração apenas pelos seus métodos, mas ela continua sendo uma classe normal ou não? Quando falo normal, quero dizer não `static`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sem a explícita declaração da classe como `static` ela é uma classe normal e pode ser instanciada a não ser que você impeça ([veja como nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52250/101)). Então tem implicações diferentes ter o modificador `static` além da documentação que ali só pode ter membros estáticos.

Mas deve-se perguntar porque criar uma classe normal quando todos os seus membros são estáticos. Existe alguma razão? Se não encontrar, está fazendo algo "errado".

Lembre-se que todos os membros precisam ser estáticos e não só os métodos.

Em C# 6 é possível importar classes estáticas, classes normais não, com:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
```

permite usar:

```
WriteLine(Sin(12));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4Ce4Xu). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VAuzN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Namespace/UsingStatic.cs).

Se estas classes não fossem estáticas, você não poderia fazer isto. Só para citar um exemplo.

Comment: O motivo do post foi apenas entender a teoria da coisa. Quanto a criar uma classe com métodos static e uma classe não normal, claro que isso não deve acontecer. Essa pergunta minha foi motivada pelo post de Construtor Private. Somente para entender. Às vezes em uma entrevista de emprego os caras costumam perguntar coisas para saber o nível de entendimento teórico que o candidato possui e entender é sempre bom. Já fiz muita coisa sem entender o que está se fazendo e isso é ruim. Hoje resolvi uma situação de lógica para o colega pelo simples entender da coisa. Isso é muito bom.

Comment: @pnet entendi e percebi a intenção. Olha, pode até ter motivo, veja o exemplo na minha resposta no *link* que passei na resposta), ali é tudo estático, não pode instanciar a classe (porque o construtor é privado) e a classe não é estática. É raro precisar, mas existe caso.

Comment: Ok, registrei na área 51 e está dando Unregistered user. Não entendi.

Answer (score 2):

Ela continua sendo uma classe não-estática, pois você pode instanciá-la.

Os métodos estáticos são idênticos em todas as instâncias de objetos da classe.

Os atributos estáticos são idênticos em todas as instâncias de objetos da classe, como os métodos. Um uso comum de atributos estáticos é a contagem de objetos daquela classe.

Comment: Um método estático não tem acesso direto a variáveis não estáticas de uma instância de sua classe.

Comment: Tem sentido. Editado.