# Como adicionar um elemento em uma lista?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Qual a sintaxe correta para chamar o método `Add_Pessoa` da classe `ClsPessoa` por uma Lista?

```
public class ClsPessoa
{
    private static string PSTR_Nome = "";
    private static DateTime PDT_DataNascimento;
    private static string PSTR_Email = "";

    public ClsPessoa()
    {
    }

    static public string Nome
    {
        get { return PSTR_Nome; }
        set { PSTR_Nome = value; }
    }

    static public DateTime DataNascimento
    {
        get { return PDT_DataNascimento; }
        set { PDT_DataNascimento = value; }
    }

    static public string Email
    {
        get { return PSTR_Email; }
        set { PSTR_Email = value; }
    }       

    public void Add_Pessoa(string PV_Nome, DateTime PV_DataNascimento, string PSTR_Email)
    {
        Nome = PV_Nome;
        DataNascimento = PV_DataNascimento;
        Email = PSTR_Email;
    }
```

Algo assim?

```
var pessoas = new List<ClsPessoa>();
pessoas[0].Add_Pessoa(TXT_Nome.Text, DTP_DataNascimento.DisplayDate, TXT_Email.Text);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não confunda o objeto `Pessoa` e o objeto `List<Pessoa>`. São coisas distintas. Então você não pode "adicionar uma pessoa em uma pessoa". Olha como a frase não faz sentido. Você pode "adicionar uma pessoa à uma lista de pessoas". Então as operações são separadas.

Se vai adicionar, você não escolhe em que posição vai colocar. E assim como no *array*, você tem criar uma instância da classe desejada e então adicionar a instância:

```
var pessoas = new List<ClsPessoa>();
pessoas.Add(new ClsPessoa() {Nome = TXT_Nome.Text,
                             DataNascimento = DTP_DataNascimento.DisplayDate,
                             Email = TXT_Email.Text});
```

Se quiser mudar o conteúdo da posição 0 na lista aí usaria:

```
pessoas[0] = new ClsPessoa() {Nome = TXT_Nome.Text,
                              DataNascimento = DTP_DataNascimento.DisplayDate,
                              Email = TXT_Email.Text});
```

Ou se quiser mudar uma propriedade:

```
pessoas[0].Email = TXT_Email.Text;
```

Mas tem um jeito melhor de montar a classe toda:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public Pessoa(string nome, DateTime dataNascimento, string email) {
        Nome = nome ?? ""; //esquisito, mas é o que tinha no código original
        DataNascimento = dataNascimento;
        Email = email ?? "";
    }
    public string Nome { get; set;}
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AddObject.cs).

Olha como ficou mais simples. Com nomes melhores, sem usar [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101) que é horrível e não ajuda nada, [sem usar coisas fora do padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101). Com sintaxe simplificada de [propriedades automáticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90736/101). Usando o [construtor da forma correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) e evitando um método auxiliar que não servia para nada. E principalmente consertando o problema dos membros estáticos. Se vai criar uma classe que precisa ser instanciada, ou seja, vai criar um objeto com dados nela, os membros do objeto não podem ser estáticos.

Ainda dá para melhorar várias coisas nesta classe. Mas vamos por partes. Uma delas seria nem ter um construtor. Neste caso ele não está sendo especialmente útil. Só não digo que ele é completamente desnecessário porque não conheço o requisito. Consigo enxergar algum motivo para tê-lo.

Se realmente precisa ter um classe para abstrair melhor uma lista de pessoas, então outra classe precisa ser criada. Mas isto já é outro assunto.

Se fizer isto, aí pode mudar um pouco a sintaxe acima, embora não vá fazer muita diferença. Eu acho a primeira forma mais legível. Embora dê para deixar a forma abaixo mais legível também. Mas deixa para depois, não vou encher de novidades na sua cabeça.

```
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(Nome.Text,
                       DataNascimento.DisplayDate,
                       Email.Text));
```

Sei que te apresentei várias coisas novas, dê uma pesquisada, se não encontrar nada aqui, faça uma pergunta sobre o que ficou com dúvida (uma pergunta por assunto) e responderemos.

Saiba mais sobre membros estáticos em:

- [Qual a função de um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101)
- [Qual o comportamento de variáveis estáticas no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27776/101)
- [Classes estáticas e classes com métodos estáticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52367/101)

Comment: Apenas uma pequena nota: com esse construtor, as propriedades `Nome` e `DataNascimento` deveriam ter o `set` privado.

Comment: @ramaral Até acho que é uma possibilidade. Mas não obrigatoriedade. Ele só deveria ser privado se não quiser deixar as propriedades serem alteradas publicamente. Em geral, não é o que se deseja. A não ser que deseja que o objeto seja imutável. Mas aí também teria que mudar mais algumas coisas.

Comment: Pô, muito obrigado pela resposta ... entendi perfeitamente o que quer dizer ... =D facilitou muito a minha aprendizagem.

Comment: @Ayo se a resposta de bigown responde à sua dúvida, sinta-se à vontade para aceitá-la clicando no marcador à esquerda da resposta dele.

Comment: @bigown Só mais uma pergunta. Por que usar `var` em vez de         `List<ClsPessoa> pessoas = new List<ClsPessoa>();`

Comment: @Ayo Tem um *link* na resposta falando em detalhes sobre isto. Se você seguir todos os *links* que coloco, vai aprender muita coisa interessante. Na verdade se pesquisar aqui no site vai achar muita coisa que vai ajudar seu aprendizado. Eu especialmente gosto de responder coisas que ensinem as pessoas programar mais do que dar um receita de bolo para elas. Veja as minhas respostas na *tag* C#, especialmente as mais votadas, e vai abrindo novas perguntas sempre que tiver alguma dúvida que vai surgindo durante o aprendizado e não tiver aqui ainda.