# Por que declarar método __construct() vazio?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método, construtor

Compreendi o uso do método `__construct()` quando queremos receber informações assim que um objeto é instanciado como parâmetro, porém eu estou vendo uma forma diferente em sua utilização e quero saber seu motivo.

Código para exemplo (não há erros nele):

```
final class Connection{

private function __construct(){}

public static function open($name)
{
    //Verifica se existe este banco de dados e sua configuração
    if (file_exists("config/{$name}.ini")) {
        $db = parse_ini_file("config/{$name}.ini");
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Arquivo '$name' não encontrado");
    }
    //Lê as informações contidas no arquivo
    $user = isset($db['user']) ? $db['user'] : NULL;
    $pass = isset($db['pass']) ? $db['pass'] : NULL;
    $name = isset($db['name']) ? $db['name'] : NULL;
    $host = isset($db['host']) ? $db['host'] : NULL;
    $type = isset($db['type']) ? $db['type'] : NULL;
    $port = isset($db['port']) ? $db['port'] : NULL;

    //Descobre qual o tipo (driver) de banco de dados a ser utilizado
    switch ($type) {
        case 'mysql';
            $port = $port ? $port : '3306';
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host}; port={$port};dbname={$name}", $user, $pass);
            break;
    }

    //Define para que o PDO lance exeções na ocorrência de erros
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $conn;
}
```

}

Queria compreender o motivo da criação do método `__construct()` vazio e qual é seu comportamento assim.

Comment: Sei que internamente, mesmo sem o declarar, ele é chamado. Caso queira especificar alguma adição obrigatório na instância do objeto, é utilizado ele na classe. Então quer dizer que estando declarado vazio, seria o mesmo que não criar?

Comment: @LucasAlvesdaMota o método é chamado na inicialização da classe, logo você acaba criando a instância da classe, mas em um construtor vazio, o que tá dentro da classe não é instanciado (se não for instanciado fora do construtor).

Comment: **private** function __construct não faz sentido, esse código não funciona, ele causará `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to private Connection::__construct() from invalid context`, justamente por que é PRIVATE.

Answer (score 4):

Note que este caso específico o construtor é privado, portanto somente a classe pode chamá-lo.

Desta forma a sua ou qualquer aplicação não pode instanciar essa classe. É uma forma de obrigar chamar um método estático para executar o que precisa sem que seja instanciado um objeto ou ele seja instanciado internamente.

Se o construtor é privado e ele não tem o que fazer (o caso) então ele não deve ter corpo.

No exemplo mostrado não é instanciado, então a classe não faz o menor sentido existir, o código foi escrito por quem não sabe programar bem, foi escrito com dogmas, do tipo "o código todo deve ser orientado a objeto, e por isso tudo deve estar dentro de uma classe", o que não tem qualquer justificativa plausível, é só regra que alguém inventou sabe-se lá porque e que algumas pessoas seguem sem pensar no que está fazendo.

Ali uma função solta resolve o problema, por isso não serve nem como classe Factory. O problema é que a pessoa que fez aprendeu cim uma linguagem que exige que tudo esteja dentro de uma classe e transpôs para PHP que não exige, ou seja a pessoa não aprendeu a programar, só decorou uma receita de bolo, escreveu um livro (segundo comentário abaixo) e agora ensina errado outras pessoas.

A não ser que o código postado não seja o real, mas parece que é.

O código tem outros problemas. O maior problema de aprender olhando código dos outros é que se você não é experiente não sabe dizer se é um bom código ou não, então pode aprender de forma errada.

Um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52250/101) onde há motivação real em outra linguagem.

Comment: O contexto do código trata-se do design patterns factory. contido no livro: *Dall'Oglio, Pablo. PHP Programando com Orientação a Objetos (p. 328). Novatec Editora*. Ele faz a leitura de uma arquivo de configuração para o banco de dados e esta classe específica tem o objetivo de ser "inalterável". Mas obrigado pela resposta, compreendi o motivo da declaração do método __construct vazio, sendo para tornar obrigatório a não permissão de instância da classe que, em seu contexto faz sentido. Parece confuso, pois ele é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Isso não é uma factory https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101

Comment: Bom, segundo o livro trata-se o do patterns Factory Method. Porém obrigado pela resposta, irei procurar saber mais.

Comment: Joga fora o livro.

Comment: Me indique um bom livro a respeito do assunto. Obrigado.

Comment: Em PHP eu não sei, quase todo material que eu vi é ruim, a maioria cai no que eu falei na resposta, falam de crenças e não de conhecimento universal. Pode ter algo bom mas eu desconheço.

Comment: No caso, o livro citado por mim é a referência no país sobre o assunto, escrito pelo pioneiro do assunto no país. Quando pesquiso sobre o padrão, encontro que trata-se exatamente de um padrão, chamado Factory Method. Padrão amplamente utilizado. Agora, caso contenha alguma erro e/ou seja o objetivo do autor, pois na dinâmica do livro, o autor trata de formas "não aconselháveis" para depois  mostrar opções mais elegantes. Porèm eu não observei isto neste capítulo, apenas no capítulo 3, que é explicitamente enunciado esta intenção.

Comment: No _Effective Java_ esse padrão de encapsular construtor privado em método estático é o _static factory method_ (e o livro faz questão de frisar que não é o mesmo que o _factory method_ do GoF).

Comment: No caso, estou me referindo ao contexto que justifica a existência da classe. A classe exemplo, que utilizei neste post é referente a uma classe de transação, sendo utilizada juntamente com uma classe no padrão Factory method para a conexão com o banco de dados. Pois o colega acima relatou que o objetivo da classe não faria sentindo, sendo que, em seu contexto, é impedir que a classe seja instanciada. Por isto mesmo que foi declarado o construtor como private, assim cumpre o objetivo. Como você mesmo citou. Eu não sabia desta opção, pro isto a existência deste post.

Answer (score -6):

Se você não precisa de um construtor o ideal é nem declarar, nesse caso o método não tem nenhum comportamento, basicamente ao instanciar uma classe do tipo Connection o fluxo do programa vai passar pelo construtor, mas como não possui nenhum comando vai só seguir em frente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).